# Is it possible to get the decimals of a given place?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu-architecture

A few years ago one of my friends had made a pi program which got the decimals of pi, so if you put a function call to it like `bufferPi(5)`, it would get the 5th decimal place of pi. Now, obviously due to the limits of computing and for reasons I don't understand much, it's not possible to get a decimal place past a certain point.

So, let's say I had a greyscale image which was 2x2 (meaning 4 pixels in area), there would be 256 possible shades of grey ranging from pure black to pure white. Each pixel has 256 possible shades, meaning there is 256^4 shades of grey which could be used in different combinations in the image.

However, as the image gets bigger so does the amount of shades, eventually surpassing the limit of 64-bit computing (just below 2^1024) Is there any way, especially in programming/math, to get the digits afterwards or is this simply impossible to represent?

An example: Take a number which is bigger than 2^1024- in traditional programming this would be an infinite, unrepresentable number which the compiler usually just gives as "inf" or "infinity". Of course, I could shorten the number below this range and get those digits, but is there any way to get the digits **after** that range. See below for more detail.

I know it is possible to some extent. See the Great Internet Mersenne Prime Search for an example. It gives you a mersenne prime (a number to the power of 2, minus one) for your computer to try and see if there is any factors of.

This works on 64-bit computers, but these primes are often 2 to the power of tens of millions which is *exponentially* greater than 2^1024. How do they do this, since these numbers are much much **much** greater than the limit, so how would a computer even be able to represent the number without running out of memory and having to resort to the traditional "inf".

Sorry for the vague question but hopefully someone knows the answer, not so much for the first one but an answer to the last would be *deeply appreciated*. Thank you! c:

Comment: Is there a way to note down a decimal number when the space on one sheet of paper runs out?

Comment: Good analogy but I get it now thanks to the guy who answered below :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question, essentially when we talk about 64-bit computers, each elementary unit of data is 64 bits in size (e.g. address lengths, integer sizes etc...). This makes it easy to add numbers that are under this size but to go over this limit we need to split the numbers into many parts.

For example, lets consider a 4 bit computer to make things easier:
We want to add the numbers u = 01001010 and v = 00101011 but the problem is that they are too big to store therefore lets spilt these numbers into parts of 2:

> a = 0100     b = 1010  (splitting u through the middle)
>
> x = 0010     y = 1011  (splitting v through the middle)

which follows that:

> a + x =  0110
>
> b + y =  **1**0101     <- this is too big!

now technically a + x is supposed to have an extra 4 zeros on the end so when we add a+x and b+y we actually need to add:

> 01100000 + 10101

But we can't tell the computer to do this because it can only add numbers up to 4 bits in length.

Therefore we need to add 0110 and 1 to get 0111 which makes our first value. And our second value then becomes 0101.

Therefore the way the final result would be stored is 0111 and 0101 (which is equal to 01110101 but the computer can't store this in 1 memory location).

This is how computers store and use arithmetic on larger numbers than the bit count can allow, by using clever tricks to add and multiply parts of the number and then storing each part in memory at separate addresses which is how computers store massive numbers like the decimal points of pi.

Comment: Thank you so much! I always thought they split up the number but I didn't know how they put it back together again, and your post greatly explains this. Unfortunately my upvote isn't public since I have less than 15 reputation, but if I could I would c: